# Where there is a centos 5.4 server security configuration and installation guide?

Tags: centos

Where there is a centos 5.4 server security configuration and installation guide (chinese tutorial)?
I have dell pc now and i want to use it study how to config centos server.
So can you give me some suggestions? thank you .

Answer (score 3):

You could use [NSA](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/os/redhat/rhel5-guide-i731.pdf)'s security guide.

Comment: what's this? can save my issue?

Comment: ok i konw what about NSA's but i want to Chinese Tutorial